# unset id field from a document in mongdb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have document as below. What i am trying to do is unset id and keep _id from each document.

```
 "educations": [
 {
   "_id": ObjectId("58ec7aaaa3c19b8793805cca00e"),
   "school": "xyz",
   "type": "pqr",
   "updatedAt": ISODate("2017-04-11T06:36:03.588Z"),
   "createdAt": ISODate("2015-03-05T12:32:26.735Z"),
   "obj_type": "education",
   "current": false
 },
 {
   "_id": ObjectId("58eceeeee353c19b673805cca00f"),
   "school": "KTH",
   "type": "tun",
   "updatedAt": ISODate("2017-04-11T06:36:03.588Z"),
   "createdAt": ISODate("2015-02-16T23:17:12.393Z"),
   "obj_type": "education",
   "id": ObjectId("574eassssh83cbee22336d2d4"),
   "current": false
 },
 {
   "createdAt": ISODate("2016-08-19T07:31:12.640Z"),
   "updatedAt": ISODate("2016-08-19T07:31:12.640Z"),
   "type": "abc",
   "school": "KTH",
   "duration": "3+ år",
   "_id": ObjectId("57bsssss687dfec6716dd75"),
   "current": false
 }
```

]

```
var query = {
             $unset: {} 
            };
query.$unset['profile.educations.'+index+'.id'] = 1;
models.User.update({_id: user._id},query, function(err, val){
      //some operation
 });
```

what have I done wrong here? Some suggestions are highly appreciated. It works removing it in the mongo console, with the same query.

Comment: Your document does not seem to have a `profile` root key for the embedded subdocument `'profile.educations.'+index+'.id'`, did you perhaps mean `'educations.'+index+'.id'`?

Comment: @chridam its a subdocument of profile originally

Comment: Can you show the full document structure i.e. the `User` model's schema definition?

Comment: @chridam I tried unsetting other field than id e.g type. I worked fine. Now i am wondering if it is not possible to unset id/_id field from the document since it is regarded as the primary key

Comment: @bureaquete I am trying to drop id not _id, and as I have mentioned, i was able to drop it from the mongodb console.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question, can you try this -> `User.collection.update( { id : { $exists : true } }, { $unset { id : "" } } )`

Comment: which mongoose version are you using?

Answer (score -1):

You can use code like this:

```
db.collection.find({
        educations: {
            $exists: true
        }
    }).forEach(function(myDoc) {
        var child = myDoc.educations;
        for (var i = 0; i < child.length; i++) {
            var ob = child[i];
            if ('id' in ob) {
                delete ob.id;
                child[i] = ob;
            }
        }db.collection.update({
            _id: myDoc._id
         }, {
            $set: {
                educations: child
            }
        });
        printjson(myDoc);
    });
```

(Or)
You try this one also,

```
db.collection.update({
   "educations.id": {$exists: true}
},{
   $unset: {
      "educations.$.id" : true
   }
},false,true)
```

Comment: it did not help